# How can I return values in one cell based on a range of values in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am creating a spreadsheet for a racing league and would like driver points to be automatically calculated based on finishing position.

1. Each finishing position from 1st to 10th has an associated point value, while positions 11 to 25 recieve no points.
2. Additionally, the driver with the fastest lap overall has `1` added to their points.

## Points by  Position

| Position | Point Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 18 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 |

## My Formula

I thought IF functions might work, such as `=IF(G2=1,25, )`, but I'm not sure how I could include the other finishing positions (2-10) and the other points values (18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1).

## Desired Results

- example where the 1st place finisher in `G5` also had the fastest overall lap, ie. `25+1=26`:

|  | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Race Finish** | **Driver Points** |
| **2** | 7 | 6 |
| **3** | 2 | 18 |
| **4** | 4 | 12 |
| **5** | **`1`** | **`26`** |
| **6** | 3 | 15 |
| **7** | 9 | 2 |
| **8** | 8 | 4 |
| **9** | 5 | 10 |
| **10** | 10 | 1 |
| **11** | 6 | 8 |

[image: Image of table]

Comment: Try `=choose(G9, 25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1)`.